# Android - Indeterminate ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am using the code from this website (http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog) in my App.
It is somewhat working, but not entirely:

When I press Button X, a method is called, and while it is working, the progress bar is shown. After the method is done, another activity is started. So far everything is working fine. But when I press the "BACK" button on my phone, the progress bar is shown again, and appears to be doing nothing.

What can I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dismiss the progress bar at the same time that you start the second activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, this solved my problem. There is however another small "problem": The progressDialog is not showing an animation (in the emulator). Do you know what the reason for that could be?

Comment: I've seen things like this when running on an underpowered machine. It could be just lag in getting the graphics to the screen, particularly if the async task is doing a lot of work in the background. Can you monitor your cpu usage?

Comment: I think my machine should have enough power; sometimes the animation is shown, sometimes it is not. It's not that big a deal though; thank you for your help!